# MAC-address like characters preceding username in Mac OS X prompt

Tags: macos, terminal

I really cannot remember since when this began to occur or what I did immediately before this occurred for the first time, but the terminal prompt now includes a little network card MAC address-like dash-separated alphanumeric string before my username:

[image]

In the photo it's the "b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96"

It doesn't change if I restart or do anything else. I got this Mac only two months ago and know very little about the environment. I don't remember seeing this string a couple of weeks ago. What is this string and can I hide it or get rid of it?

**ADDED** reply to user Ravachol's comment here:
Typing `echo $PS1` in the terminal yields:

```
\h:\W \u\$
```

Typing `hostname` in the terminal yields:

```
b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96.connectify
```

I am actually currently traveling, using a little Windows 7 netbook with an app called Connectify to rebroadcast the WiFi signal. Connectify's strength lies in that it can use the SAME WiFi adapter to both receive a WiFi signal that's Internet-bound and turn itself into a router and rebroadcast that Internet-bound WiFi signal.

On the Connectify interface on Windows, I see that my iPod Touch is a client, labeled "Nik's iPod Touch", and "b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96" is also a client. "b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96" is the same as what precedes my username in the terminal, the core of this post. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you tell us what is the result of "echo $PS1" ? Also, do you have a mention of PS1 in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile ?  (~/ being your home directory)

Comment: Ho and these hex numbers seem to be your hostname. Can you please type "hostname" and tell us what is outputs ? I'd guess your hostname is b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96 OR that the encoding of the hostname is not supported.

Comment: Is Connectify running on your Mac, or some other network client software (e.g. VPN)?

Comment: Hi Daniel, no Connectify is Windows only. I am running Connectify on Windows 7 on a netbook. It creates an Access Point which my Mac is connected to in order to use the internet.

Comment: What do you want your prompt to look like?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I just wondered why this MAC address like string is now showing and I want to remove it from the prompt: it's quite long and takes up space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like your Mac's hostname has changed to be equal to its MAC address. Check System Preferences → Sharing and see what the computer name is. Changing the computer name here changes what "`hostname`" returns in the terminal.

Alternatively, if you want the prompt to just show the current directory, edit the file `~/.bash_profile` and add the line `export PS1="[\W]\$ "`.  If you already have a PS1 line, then replace it with this one. There are also [other special sequences you can add to your .bash_profile](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html) if you so desire.

Your prompt right now is:

```
b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96:~ nikso$
```

Which looks like:

```
(hostname):(current directory) (username)$
```

Which matches your $PS1:

```
\h:\W \u\$

\h: Hostname up to the first "."
\W: Current directory
\u: Username
\$: A literal "$", unless you are UID 0, then "#"
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, my computer's name is Nik's Macbook Air. and I just ran a little test where I closed out all terminal windows, turned off Wifi. reopened terminal. And now it displays Niks-MacBook-Air:~nikso$ is there! And when I turned back on the Wifi, I didn't even need to open up a new terminal, just a new tab and it shows that MAC Address. But my .bash_profile doesn't have that line. It has something about rvm,the ruby version manager. Should I just add to it anyways?

Comment: @Nik: Yes, if you add that line to ~/.bash_profile then your prompt will just show the current directory. The default PS1 comes from /etc/bashrc

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be standard behavior for Connectify:

http://support.connectify.me/entries/20472872-how-can-i-rename-a-client

> Connectify usually displays the hostname for client machines that connect to your network.
>   Sometimes however, Connectify is unable to get the machines' name from it automatically
>   (since Apple went to iOS 4 on the iPhone, this has become unfortunately frequent).
>   When Connectify cannot find any name for a computer it will use the MAC address which is
>   generally something hard to remember like "ab-3f-2c-5d...".

Comment: oh no no, I know what you are saying, you are saying that the Connectify's displaying of that b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96 string is because it can't find my Macbook air's name, I can understand that. What I was asking was that how come my Macbook Air's terminal prompt NOW displays b8-8d-12-0a-d8-96 in front of username$. Thanks anyways

Comment: based on your comment to @Stephen Jennings below, I believe that the Connectify DHCP is setting the hostname for you.

Comment: see here for how to change it: http://superuser.com/questions/357159/os-x-terminal-showing-incorrect-hostname 
or here:
http://superuser.com/questions/49891/how-can-i-stop-mac-os-x-overriding-my-hostname-when-i-receive-a-dhcp-request-on