# Terminal host changed

Tags: macos, terminal, remote-access, localhost, hosts

I opened terminal today and realized that the usual startup text:

```
my-macbook-pro:~ myUsername$_
```

has been replaced by:

```
mscs256-24197:~ myUsername$_
```

I tried googling but couldn't find anything. I'm pretty sure the computers in our math building are named mscs-xxx (math sci comp sci) so maybe somebody logged in remotely? When I type in the command `hostname` it replies with: mcsc-24197@mySchool.edu.

Any ideas on how this could have happened (I just disabled remote login and haven't used any of those computers in months) and how to fix it would be much appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Os X uses complex auto-magic to set the host name:

1. The name provided by the DHCP or BootP server for the primary IP address
2. The first name returned by a reverse DNS (address-to-name) query for the primary IP address
3. The local hostname (set in the Sharing pane of System Preferences)
4. The name localhost

The following post provides different fixes for OS X 10.5 & 10.6+: [How can I stop Mac OS X overriding my hostname when I receive a DHCP request on Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/49891/how-can-i-stop-mac-os-x-overriding-my-hostname-when-i-receive-a-dhcp-request-on)