# modify a router's reply to macOS's reverse DNS query such that hostname defaults to the .local domain

Tags: macos, dhcp, openwrt, hostname, reverse-dns

I have read that on BSD/macOS/OS X, `hostname` is found from a search that includes [a few places](https://superuser.com/a/430209/95297). One part of the search can be a reverse DNS lookup. For DNS lookup, I observe different behavior on different machines running the same version of the OS. When checked with `host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`, one machine ("MachineA") shows a reverse DNS entry `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer MachineA.lan.` The other machines report `Host yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`. Only on MachineA does `hostname` show the `.lan` domain suffix (i.e., `MachineA.lan`). `.lan` is the domain supplied by the router, which is running openwrt. To restore `hostname` to a "normal" macOS domain value, I would like to change the router's DNS entry for the IP address of MachineA. That is, I would like to void the entry so that, as elsewhere, the reverse DNS returns null and macOS advances to the next step of its `hostname` value search. How can/should this be accomplished?

Note, I am aware that an option is to set a value in `/etc/hostconfig` or in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` via `scutil` but, these solutions would appear to deviate from "standard/default" macOS configuration. For similar reasons, I would like to avoid using a [static address](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219209/296582) or setting a [DHCP client ID](https://superuser.com/a/50039/952974).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reverse DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/glossary/reverse-dns/) checks a [PTR record](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-ptr-record/). Records seem to be stored in [RAM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163075). For me, restatring `dnsmasq` seemed to work: `./etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart`. This may have flushed the cache. That is not a complete answer as something else must have changed in the config at some point such that restart was sufficient. Still, problem solved: `host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
now results in `Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`.